# Always getting message on startup: "Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 180 seconds"

Tags: solr

Version: Solr 6.3

OS: CentOs 7.3

After installation when running `service solr restart`, after 180 seconds I always get the same message before the INFO messages print out.

```
$ service solr restart
Archiving 1 old GC log files to /var/solr/logs/archived
Archiving 1 console log files to /var/solr/logs/archived
Rotating solr logs, keeping a max of 9 generations
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [-]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 180 seconds!
```

What's weird is that the Solr server comes up and is accessible via the web interface almost immediately, however the full 180 seconds are spent waiting only to throw that message out each time. What causes this message and how can I get Solr identified to be running sooner?

Thanks!

Comment: use script file in bin folder  `bin/solr start`

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks almost everything (shows I have no cores), and ultimately still gives the same message after a full 180 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like either Solr not running on that port or it listens on specific interface and the checker scripts is using a default (localhost?) one. Can you run that with debug or check the definitions in the startup script?

Comment: I believe it's the second part. I am pretty sure the problem is trying to listen on localhost. I know that's problematic because when I add localhost to the Jetty IP access whitelist it cannot connect to it's own solr instance. I need to add the external IP for the box to reach it's own solr. I can either fix that so localhost works properly (preferable), or change the listener to listen for the server IP. Do you know where the checker script lives (or why localhost might be broken)?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message trying to start solr: "Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 180 seconds!". However, I couldn't access solr's web interface either. Checking the log files in /var/log/solr I read the following error message:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /tmp/start_6692986047430088693.properties
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:897)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.StartArgs.getMainArgs(StartArgs.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:458)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

The problem was that I was inside a FreeBSD jail that had unusual permissions set on the /tmp directory (also on /var/tmp). Fixing the permissions on these directories solved the problem:

```
# chmod 1777 /tmp /var/tmp
```

I realize the cause of your problem is probably different. But since the error message is the same, I thought it could be useful to add this solution here.